# Как активировать дату в таблице базы данных PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Информация из формы сайта (имя, е-mail, сообщение) передается в БД. Как в таблицу БД  занести дату отправки сообщения из сайта? Строка ДАТА в таблице БД есть, но там отображаются `0000.00.00`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в PHPMyAdmin (удобнее) изменить тип данных столбца даты на TIMESTAMP. Тогда при отправки пустого значения запишется текущая дата вида 0000-00-0000:00:00.

Comment: Спасибо! Просто!! Действительно только  изменила тип данных дата на TIMESTAMP и в столбце появилась информация времени отправки сообщения !

Answer (score 0):

Выражу ИМХО! Лучше записывать просто time() и при выводе или запросах уже разбирать на запчасти. Но каждый конечно делает тот велосипед на котором ему будет удобней ездить.

Comment: лично я тоже предпочитаю юзать timestamp, но если юзать его, то далеко не каждый потом может номрально делать выборку и спортировку, если у вас все нормально с SQL'ем то ИМХО timestamp лучшее решение